# fatal: unknown value for config 'protocol.version': 2

Tags: git

I decided to turn on Git protocol 2nd ver (I suppose it's faster, noiseless), so I did:

```
git config --global protocol.version 2
```

But when I try

```
git pull
```

I get an error saying:

```
fatal: unknown value for config 'protocol.version': 2
```

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04. My friend on Ubuntu 16.04 did the same and it worked for him. Am I maybe missing some dependencies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature appeared in [Git 2.18](https://opensource.googleblog.com/2018/05/introducing-git-protocol-version-2.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+GoogleOpenSourceBlog+%28Google+Open+Source+Blog%29&utm_content=Google+International)

> To try out protocol version 2 for yourself you'll need an up to date version of Git (support for v2 was recently merged to Git's master branch and is expected to be part of Git 2.18) and a v2 enabled server (repositories on googlesource.com and Cloud Source Repositories are v2 enabled).

And I have Git 2.17v

Comment: And my friend's git 2.7 ver, and it ignore protocol version (hi try set 4 ver and had no errors)

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), The transport protocol version 2 (that [I presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50273976/6309) before) becomes the **default one**.
(It was reverted in 2.27, but is the default again in Q4 2020 with Git 2.29: see below)

See [commit 684ceae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/684ceae32dae726c6a5c693b257b156926aba8b7), [commit 33166f3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33166f3a1fcc77824e162d8a8e51ee8b4a2b481c), [commit 8a1b097](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a1b0978abf8b3fb0ee2dc7a7d71766ed0ef4768), [commit b9ab170](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9ab170752f39f4a72e3595129735c87a491dffd), [commit 07ef3c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/07ef3c6604c7c3da4b7279cd725cf8e5e0cf7edd) (24 Dec 2019) by [Jonathan Nieder (`artagnon`)](https://github.com/artagnon).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0da63da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0da63da7942ce810126cd54d9f72a46f3d616895), 14 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`config doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9ab170752f39f4a72e3595129735c87a491dffd): protocol.version is not experimental
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Nieder</sup>
>
> Git's protocol version 2 has been working well in production for over a year.
>
> Simplify documentation by no longer referring to it as experimental.

And:

> ### [`fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/684ceae32dae726c6a5c693b257b156926aba8b7): default to protocol version 2
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Nieder</sup>
>
> The Git users at $DAYJOB have been using protocol v2 as a default for ~1.5 years now and others have been also reporting good experiences with it, so it seems like a good time to bump the default version.
>
> It produces a significant performance improvement when fetching from repositories with many refs, such as https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.
>
> This only affects the client, not the server.
>
> (The server already defaults to supporting protocol v2.)
> The protocol change is backward compatible, so this should produce no significant effect when contacting servers that only speak protocol v0.

---

Warning: before Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), those fetching over protocol v2 from linux-next and other kernel repositories are reporting that v2 often fetches way too much than needed.

See [commit 11c7f2a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/11c7f2a30b9dadcccc7bde66a34e0cb0cb5cf52c) (22 Apr 2020) by [Jonathan Nieder (`artagnon`)](https://github.com/artagnon).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e896a28](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e896a286df44d9d0ae9a81bf172236dd521f5c39), 28 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`Revert "fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/11c7f2a30b9dadcccc7bde66a34e0cb0cb5cf52c): default to protocol version 2"
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Lubomir Rintel</sup>
> <sup>Reported-by: "Dixit, Ashutosh"</sup>
> <sup>Reported-by: Jiri Slaby</sup>
> <sup>Reported-by: Konstantin Ryabitsev</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Nieder</sup>
>
> This reverts [commit 684ceae32dae726c6a5c693b257b156926aba8b7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/684ceae32dae726c6a5c693b257b156926aba8b7).
>
> Users fetching from linux-next and other kernel remotes are reporting that the limited ref advertisement causes negotiation to reach `MAX_IN_VAIN,` resulting in too-large fetches.

---

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), The transport protocol v2 has become the default again.

See [commit eb04975](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb049759fb6b739310af52ee0e13ce6cd0c86be7) (25 Sep 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e76ae33](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e76ae330099f97d3a868cacf311f420203f51a67), 29 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`protocol`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb049759fb6b739310af52ee0e13ce6cd0c86be7): re-enable v2 protocol by default
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> Protocol v2 became the default in v2.26.0 via [684ceae32d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/684ceae32dae726c6a5c693b257b156926aba8b7) ("`fetch`: default to protocol version 2", 2019-12-23, Git v2.26.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0da63da7942ce810126cd54d9f72a46f3d616895) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7ae7e234c7e75dace3ba8aa8d87166ac7d75d7dd)).
>
> More widespread use turned up a regression in negotiation. That was fixed in v2.27.0 via [4fa3f00abb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4fa3f00abb55c3334cce71e201a5ff2c70f8561f) (`fetch-pack`: in protocol v2, `in_vain` only after ACK, 2020-04-27), but we also reverted the default to v0 as a precaution in [11c7f2a30b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/11c7f2a30b9dadcccc7bde66a34e0cb0cb5cf52c) (Revert "`fetch`: default to protocol version 2", 2020-04-22).
>
> In v2.28.0, we re-enabled it for experimental users with [3697caf4b9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3697caf4b962f65430fdcd6f0d41b7fe1f579e18) ("`config`: let feature.experimental imply protocol.version=2", 2020-05-20, Git v2.28.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/51b47088112d4d4521d6f07c51f70c3ab4e07b63) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0313f36c6ebecb3bffe6f15cf25a4883100f0214)) and haven't heard any complaints.
>
> v2.28 has only been out for 2 months, but I'd generally expect people turning on feature.experimental to also stay pretty up-to-date. So we're not likely to collect much more data by waiting. In addition, we have no further reports from people running v2.26.0, and of course some people have been setting protocol.version manually for ages.
>
> Let's move forward with v2 as the default again. It's possible there are still lurking bugs, but we won't know until it gets more widespread use. And we can find and squash them just like any other bug at this point.
>
> If unset, the default is `2`.

Answer (score -1):

The Git manual for `config` (`man git-config` on Git v2.20.1) says:

```
protocol.version
    Experimental. If set, clients will attempt to communicate with a server
    using the specified protocol version. If unset, no attempt will be made by
    the client to communicate using a particular protocol version, this results
    in protocol version 0 being used. Supported versions:

    ·   0 - the original wire protocol.

    ·   1 - the original wire protocol with the addition of a version string in
        the initial response from the server.

    ·   2 - wire protocol version 2[2].
```

So `2` is not a valid value for `protocol.version`, and your friend probably set it to `1`.

Comment: on version 2.20.1, it also says: `2 - wire protocol version 2[2].`