# Invoking git-upload-pack with write protocol v2

Tags: git

The [document](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/protocol-v2.txt) for running Git wire protocol v2 states that in order to invoke `git-upload-pack` with protocol v2, one needs to run it with an environment variable `GIT_PROTOCOL` containing `version=2`. I do that by running in terminal:

```sh
GIT_PROTOCOL='version=2' bash -c 'git upload-pack .'
```

But I still get v1 protocol running. I see that from the response of v1 form:

```sh
00f2562e09028aef13e2e4fa9483bf32a26329de78e1 HEADmulti_ack thin-pack side-band side-band-64k ofs-delta shallow deepen-since deepen-not deepen-relative no-progress include-tag multi_ack_detailed symref=HEAD:refs/heads/master agent=git/2.15.1
<truncated>
```

Could somebody help me to either find what I'm doing wrong or understand how to invoke `git-upload-pack` with wire protocol version 2?

Comment: Does the remote server supports V2?

Comment: What version of Git are you using and on what OS?

Comment: @bk2204 git v  2.15.1 and MacOS Catalina

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/a/38474220/6309 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/60253725/6309, 2.15 seems a bit old to support *by default* a V2 protocol.

Comment: @VonC I am not expecting it to support v2 by default. That's why I'm running it with special env var GIT_PROTOCOL='version=2'

Comment: I meant, `GIT_PROTOCOL='version=2'` might not mean much for a Git 2.15.

Comment: Why do you run an intermediat bash shell? What shell do you run that code in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git 2.15 doesn't support the v2 protocol.  The code to handle this environment variable didn't exist until at least 2.16, and the full v2 protocol was not in until later.  You'll need a newer version of Git; I recommend the one from Homebrew.

On my system, with 2.29, I get the following:

```
$ GIT_PROTOCOL='version=2' bash -c 'git upload-pack .' | head -n1
000eversion 2
```